# Подключить компомненты apache к java

Tags: java, java-ee, httpclient, apache-modules

Не получается настроить/подключить компоненты сервера.

Подключал компоненты:

httpcomponents-client-4.5.2-bin.zip
apache-httpcomponents-httpcore.jar

пробовал разные версии, бинарные файлы, нескомпилированные классы java

Результат один - куча нераспознанных классов, констант, методов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Error:(3, 23) java: package org.apache.http does not exist
```

День на это потратил, разумеется гуглил на англ. Решений не нашел.

нашел http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

скачал все, что мог, присоеднили к проекту, но результат тот же.

Comment: Попробуйте Maven. В нём удобно работать с зависимостями. (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents)

Comment: Вот тут полезная тема: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491457/how-to-use-httpclient-4-1-x-with-maven

Comment: Вы просто закидываете JAR-ник в проект? Так делать не нужно. В IDEA очень просто подключаются библиотеки, это во-первых. Во-вторых, рано или поздно столкнётесь с Maven, так что советую прочитать немного про него. Вам никакой крутой уровень пока что не нужен, просто о том, как это работает, как включаются зависимости (библиотеки) и о жизненном цикле. В IDEA по умолчанию есть встроенный плагин, там же можно сразу сгенерировать  Maven-управляемый проект.

Comment: нет, конечно, в intelijidea подключаю как библиотеку.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать алгоритм как правильно подлючить при помощи maven, раз все советуют?